# Change color of the spesific building from his labels

Tags: tilemill

I just starting today to work with TileMill and I would change the color of a type of building, from his labels, that mean if I have building with (label=Hospital) that affects their a pink color. It is possibl an can someone help me please.

---

## building-labels{

```
  [toponyme = 'Hôpital']{
    polygon-fill: pink * 1.2; 
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me please, i want to add (picture.jpg) to specific polygon from a links. i do this:
[toponyme = 'Police']{ polygon-fill: "url":"C:\Temp\loubna-terrain\terrain-sport.jpg"; } and i receive this answer: Failed to parse expression: "C:\Temp\loubna-terrain\terrain-sport.jpg" in style 'batiments_labels' in PolygonSymbolizer

Comment: This is not an answer.  You need to edit your question and put this information into the question.